# Joint distribution of two uniform random variables

Tags: probability-distributions, uniform-distribution, copula

Consider two uniform random variables $U, V$ . If  $ U \sim \mbox{Uniform}(0,1)$ and $V = 1 -U$ how would we show that the joint distribution of $(U, V)$ is given by $\max \{ u + v -1,0 \}$?

The reason I ask is because the joint distribution is the lower 
Frechet-Hoeffding bound from the theory of Copulas. This makes sense intuitively given that the Frechet-Hoeffding bounds
correspond to cases of extreme dependency and if we set $V = 1 - U$, the random variables are perfectly negatively correlated. However, how can we show this result explicitly?

Comment: What do you mean joint distribution is $\max \{ u + v -1,0 \}$?

Comment: For random variables $U$ and $V$, the joint distribution $F$ is given by $$ F(u,v) = {\mathbb P}[U \leq u, V \leq v] = \max \{u + v -1,0 \} $$ when $V = 1 - U$ where $U \sim \mbox{Uniform}(0,1)$.

Comment: $P(U\le u, 1-U\le v)=P(1-v\le U\le u)$